# Windows Store App Javascript/HTML5 connect to Database

Tags: javascript, database, html, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have been creating a **HTML5/Javascript** system using Visual Studio 2013 (Blank App) now I want to use some database, I have two choice, first is to use my online MySQL database that is hosted, and second is to use a local database that is installed in my computer.

But the problems are

1.) I want to know what **kind of database** I should be using in this Windows Store App, because what I want is a database compatible/portable with Windows 8 Tablets.

2.) I don't know how can I **add,edit, and delete a database** using HTML5/Javascript since I know that javascript is not a script to do this algorithms. If so is there any possible alternatives or rather plugins/libraries to do this database connecting?

3.) I have been wondering if **XML** is a possible choice for a portable database. I need some good tutorial that is working on Windows Store App.

Please help, and I need a sincere and best answers. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use database for your app, you need to have an intermediate (PHP/ASP/Ruby), that can enable you to read/write data into database. Javascript cannot handle databases on its own. You can use MySQL for your app, as it one of easiest and most deployed database system. I would say you use JSON instead of XML. Javascript has better support for JSON and it is easy and convenient than XML. Also JSON is light-weight and simple than XML.

Comment: WebSQL is an HTML5 standard that can be considered. But its under development, plus its support is very less. So please avoid it if you come across it.

Comment: ok ZEE, i would try to use JSON on my app, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use indexeddb,websql,sqlite.
sqlite is better and easy to use.following link helps to connect to database in html5/javascript apps.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

database wrapper for html5/javascript app

https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT